# Code Colorer Being Used

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I visited [**this site**](http://www.zurb.com/article/305/easily-turn-your-images-into-polaroids-wi) and i really liked the code colorer used by it (apart from that CSS3 article on speech bubbles).

I went through the source code of that page but could not find which syntax highlighter is being used there.

Does any one have an idea?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not JavaScript or jQuery, as the HTML source already has the classes for variables, punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i can tell it's a serverside script since it isn't colored by javascript so you are out of luck on determining what script he uses by looking at the source. Perhaps contact the site owner or take a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

Answer (score 1):

That almost looks like it was hand coded because each line is on an `<li>` or more likely processed server side. Anyway, here is a post about [9 useful javascript syntax highlighter scripts](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/).

---

Update: If you listen to this [ShopTalk podcast with Doug Neiner](http://shoptalkshow.com/episodes/010-with-doug-neiner/), he actually talks about doing his syntax highlighting server side. He doesn't work for ZURB, but maybe there was an influence there?

Comment: Yeah, I woudln't go that far either LOL. Anyway, check out Chili... it's probably the most versatile code highlighter.